# How to use a form to add many children to parent of has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, parent-child, has-many-through

I'm working on an exercise app, an element of which is that a User has_many WorkoutTypes (WoType in the code) (via a has_many :through relationship), and I'd like to build a form to add more than one of each WorkoutType to a given user.

I've currently got a checkbox form working to add singular, different children to a user:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
...
...
<div class="field">
    <%= hidden_field_tag "user[wo_type_ids][]", nil %>
    <%= WoType.all.each do |wo_type| %>
        <%= check_box_tag "user[wo_type_ids][]", wo_type.id, @user.wo_type_ids.include?(wo_type.id), id: dom_id(wo_type) %>
        <%= label_tag dom_id(wo_type), wo_type.wo %><br>
    <% end %>
  </div>
...
...
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This means a user can edit their account to select one of each of, for example, run, gym, football; however, I'd like them to be able to select as many of each as they'd like though (i.e. a user have three 'runs'). Any idea how I could update the form to implement this?

Here's the abridged code for the models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wo_types, through: :wocfgs
  has_many :wocfgs, dependent: :destroy
end

class WoType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wocfgs
  has_many :users, through: :wocfgs
end

class Wocfg < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :wo_type
end
```

Bonus points: the checkbox is currently printing all of the WorkoutTypes below it in the view and I've no idea why. Any clues how to get rid of this would be great! I can't post an image as I don't have the rep, but here's a link to a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkBkJ.png.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Bonus points question first: `<%= WoType.all.each do |wo_type| %>` should be `<% WoType.all.each do |wo_type| %>`. The `=` prints everything after the loop.

About the main question: I'd use [Nested form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) to accomplish what you are doing. Nested form will allow you to add more of each checkbox to the list (via JavaScript), so when it is submitted, you can have multiple "run" checkboxes selected. I guess the one downside is that there would be links after each checkbox, which might not look the best.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan, much appreciated. I'll have a play and mark this as the answer if I can get it working!